# What's with the 70% ethanol?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Is there a reason for all the bottles being 70% ethanol, or is it convention.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Where are you seeing the bottles?

Comment: I mean that they are not 50 percent or 90 percent, but 70 %.

Comment: Could you take a picture and post it to the question? Maybe provide a little more context, at the moment it is really hard to tell what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primarily it is used as an anti-microbial agent. There is lots of data out there showing that the efficacy of ethanol at killing bacteria peaks at the 70% mixture. As they are making tons of it (literally) for the microbiologists, it's easier to just scale production then set up a new production facility for chemists to use at an arbitrary concentration.